# Grafana cannot connect to InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am sorry, can you help me, please. I have read a lot but can not find a solution.

What Grafana version and what operating system are you using?

```
operating system = Ubuntu 18.04
GRAFANA_VERSION  = 8.0.1 in docker-container
INFLUXDB_VERSION = 2.0.7 in docker-container
```

What are you trying to achieve?

```
I am trying to connect Grafana to InfluxDB
```

How are you trying to achieve it?

```
Checked InfluxDB settings:

1 user   = admin, passw 12345678
1 bucket = my-bucket
1 token  = my-secret-token
```

I have read this instruction:

```
Use Grafana with InfluxDB OSS | InfluxDB OSS 2.0 Documentation
tried to set
Data Sources / InfluxDB

InfluxQL:
URL         = http://192.168.181.128:8086

Custom HTTP Headers:
Header      = Authorization
Value       = my-secret-token
Database    = my-bucket
user        = admin
password    = 12345678
HTTP Method = get
```

What happened?

```
InfluxDB Error: Bad Request
```

What did you expect to happen?

```
Grafana is connected to InfluxDB
```

Also, I tried to ping from docker with grafana 192.168.181.128. Ping ok.
and netcat 192.168.181.128:8086 is ok too.

Comment: Could you try to mimic the auth with regular hand-crafted curl commands just to see exactly what is happening?

Comment: Can you make these work first outside docker, natively on your local or dev machine (or have all of them in a one single VM for an experiment)? For me removing the docker for a moment allowed me to understand these much better and then add the docker when things work locally.

Comment: i tried in main system:
http://localhost:8086/query?Authorization=my-secret-token&u=admin&password=12345678
i have json answer
|code|unauthorized|
|message|unauthorized access|

Comment: i dont know how to mimic the auth... if you please can explain, i will try..

Comment: and tried this in main:
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true' --data-urlencode "db=my-bucket" --data-urlencode "q=SELECT \"value\" FROM \"cpu_load_short\" WHERE \"region\"='us-west';SELECT count(\"value\") FROM \"cpu_load_short\" WHERE \"region\"='us-west'" -u admin -t "my-secret-token"
first it asks question: Enter host password for user 'admin':
i entering 12345678
answer: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}

Comment: Flux query accepted InFluxQL not

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/guides/query_data/

Comment: INFLUXDB_VERSION=2.0.7

Answer (score 1):

InfluxQL supported only in InfluxDB 1.x
2.x only Flux

that is why i cannot connect to InfluxDB by InfluxQL

Comment: The compatibility API is not help? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/api/influxdb-1x/query/

Comment: no need compatibility, will use new api, thank you friend